# generating a list of concrete objects from a list of abstract references

Tags: c#

My container object contains a private `List<AbstractBaseClass>` and several public lists of concrete types derived from the AbstractBaseClass. Objects are added into the container class by reference to the AbstractBaseClass through an `Add(AbstractBaseClass ABC)` method.

The public lists are generated from a Linq query on request

```
public List<ConcreteClass> ConcreteList
{
    get
    {
        return
            from a in _abc
            Where a is ConcreteClass
            select(a as ConcreteClass)
     }
}
```

Is this an acceptable method? Is the object cast into ConcreteClass twice here and is it inefficient.

Comment: Something to consider: [Is Is As or Is As Is?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You are reinventing a wheel that the BCL has already provided. Use `OfType<T>` to filter your mixed list for items of a given concrete type.

```
var concretes = _abc.OfType<ConcreteClass>().ToList();
```

Comment: This answer solves the immediate problem; however, casting towards a more specific type is often a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
public IEnumerable<ConcreteClass> ConcreteList 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        foreach (a in _abc) 
        {
          ConcreteClass c = a as ConcreteClass;
          if (c != null)
            yield return c;
        }
     } 
}
```

you avoid the double cast, and I think it is better to return an IEnumerable instead than a List, so that the caller would not think that the returned value can be modified.